# Invalid value encountered in arcsin [RuntimeWarning]

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a large data size file and I would like to calculate distance with given latitude and longitude values. However, I encounter the following issue only with certain input files.

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin
      return earth_radius *2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

The problem can be solved if I add in the following lines of code into my program. However, I do not wish to remove data containing null in the *Drive Mode*. What can I do to overcome such issue?

```
distdura = distdura.replace(0, np.nan)
distdura = distdura[distdura['Drive Mode'].notnull()]
```

As follows shows my program.

```
distdura = pd.read_csv(folderdir)

distdura = distdura.sort_values(by = ['AV_ID','timestamp'])
distdura['dist'] = np.concatenate(distdura.groupby(["AV_ID"]).apply(lambda x:haversine(x['Latitude'],x['Longitude'],x['Latitude'].shift(),x['Longitude'].shift())).values)
distdura = distdura[distdura["dist"] < 1]
distdura = distdura[distdura["dist"] > -0.99]
```

Following is the haversine function I've used for the above code.

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians = True, earth_radius = 6371):                      
    if to_radians:
        lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2 = np.radians([lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return earth_radius *2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
```

As follows display the sample data that does not work.
[image: Sample Data]

Comment: use `print(np.sqrt(a))` to see what value you use in `arcsin()`. As I know arcsin may need value in range `-1 .. 1`

Comment: I tried but it shows the following, which I do not quite understand it.


`[nan  0.  0.  0.]
[nan  0.  0.  0.]
[           nan 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 ... 0.00000000e+00
 8.72439077e-11 0.00000000e+00]
[nan  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[nan  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[nan  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
[nan  0.  0. ...  0.  0.  0.]
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in arcsin`

Comment: you have `arcsin( [nan 0. 0. 0.])` and problem can be `arcsin(nan)` - probably it is for `lat1` - so you have to `replace `nan` with value in range `-1...1`

Comment: you should check `print( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 )` inside `haversine`. You can also use `print()` to check separatelly values for `np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2` and `np.cos(lat1)` and `np.cos(lat2)` and `np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2`

Comment: I don't understand why. But I tried printing all the values and replace those with nan to 0. But it still gives error.